# Images wont load when i try to use mthumb.php library

Tags: php, image

I'm running Windows. When I try to use the `mthumb` class, it doesn't load the `img`.

I downloaded the entire project (including the test), and I ran it, and nothing happened.

**Here is a picture of my problem:**

[image]

**And here is a picture of the project structure:**

[image]

**Here is the syntax that the example uses. It should work, but it doesn't:**

```
<p>
// test jpg<br /> <img src="/mthumb.php?src=/tests/small.jpg&w=100&h=100" alt="test jpg" />
```

```
<p>
// test png<br /> <img src="/mthumb.php?src=/tests/medium.png&w=500&h=600" alt="test png" />
```

```
<p>
// test gif<br /> <img src="/mthumb.php?src=/tests/medium.gif&w=150&h=160" alt="test gif" />
```

```
<p>
// test large file size<br /> <img src="/mthumb.php?src=/tests/large.jpg&w=100&h=100" alt="test jpg" />
```

Comment: dont post picures of code, post code as text

Comment: Done, sorry, im new to this.

Comment: could be location of  `mthumb.php` or the image file, or the code in  `mthumb.php`

Comment: Everything is supposed to be ok, my teacher just downloaded the project from https://github.com/mindsharelabs/mthumb and worked fine. But he was on a mac,i dont really know if that's the problem here.

Comment: Hello, a friend helped me finding the answer it was simple. In order to work you need to start the src whit the root file. Example: <img src="/mthumb-master/mthumb.php?src=/tests/small.jpg&w=100&h=100" alt="test jpg" />